# Dreamweaver - Don't update links on rename

Tags: settings, dreamweaver, prompt

It is possible disable the link update prompt when rename a file in local site?

I need to duplicate and rename a lot of files and each time the prompt appear, i don't want Dreamweaver searches for links when I rename a file.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Preferences, there should be an option under General: 'Update links when moving files:'

Change this to 'Never'. I believe this is what you're after.